# When an Input is active, the placeholder's opacity or color changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I figured out how to change the placeholder's opacity and color, but I am unsure of how I can alter the same when the input is actually active. In addition, I am wanting text to be placed under the input when the input is active.

How do I change the color/opacity of a placeholder element when the input is active. Please point me in the right direction for the text under the input when it is active.

```css
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.input-borderless {
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Safari, Chrome and Opera */
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: orange;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
:placeholder-shown {
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
<input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>
```

Comment: .input-borderless:focus{opacity:0.5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```css
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.input-borderless {
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Safari, Chrome and Opera */
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: orange;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
:placeholder-shown {
  color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
:-moz-placeholder:focus {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder:focus {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Do you have any idea how to get text to show up under the input if the input is selected? For an example in the snippet you created, under that line for "eg: First and Last name" to show up under the input when selected.